# Connect Microsoft Teams on Linux Ubuntu over a proxy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, microsoft-teams, teams

The company I work forces me to use a proxy for absolute everything.

I made it work for everything on my Ubuntu machine (HTTP, apt-get, etc.), however, whenever I try to run Microsoft teams, it asks me my username and password, but when I insert them, the following error returns to me.

[image]

Why is this error - -202 ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID returning to me?
Does anybody has faced such an issue before? how to fix it?

Comment: The error indicates that your proxy is not a normal proxy but an intercepting proxy which decrypts the HTTPS data and tries to inspect it but teams does not trust the root CA used by the inspecting proxy.

Comment: @Robert is there any workaround on this issue?

Comment: If you require MS Teams for work then ask your admins how to proceed.